# How to display data from multiple tables in SQL

Tags: sql, database, join

I'm relatively new to SQL. I'm trying to figure out how to satisfy this condition:    Display `customer_id, customer_last_name, order_id,order_item_id, product_name` for any customer living in Virginia.

So far, I have this, but I'm not sure how to display the values together. Any help will be appreciated.

```
SELECT customer_id, cust_first_name
FROM demo_customers
WHERE cust_state= 'VA'

SELECT order_id
FROM demo_orders
WHERE customer_id= '1'
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to use JOINS. Try this link...
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: you can google sql join.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need a `JOIN`

```
SELECT customer_id, cust_first_name, order_id, order_item_id, product_name
FROM demo_customers
INNER JOIN demo_orders on demo_orders.customer_id = demo_customers.customer_id
WHERE cust_state= 'VA'
```